# Wikipedia API doesn't return the same content that is in HTML

Tags: wikipedia, mediawiki-api

I am trying to get a list of TV episodes from Wikipedia, and the episode list returned via the API doesn't match the one fetched via HTTP.

```
$ wget -O wiki-html -q "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Agents_of_S.H.I.E.L.D._episodes"
$ grep 'Laws of Nature' wiki-html
<td class="summary" style="text-align:left">"Laws of Nature"<sup id="cite_ref-futon_52-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-futon-52"><span>[</span>52<span>]</span></a></sup></td>
$ wget -O wiki-api -q "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=List_of_Agents_of_S.H.I.E.L.D._episodes&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json"
$ grep 'Laws of Nature' wiki-api
$
```

You can see that the "Laws of Nature" episode is present in the HTML version but not in the JSON version. There do not appear to be multiple revisions, and this problem hasn't occurred with other shows. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [the source code of the article](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_Agents_of_S.H.I.E.L.D._episodes&action=edit), you will notice code like this:

```
===Season 3=== <!--Do not add years until episodes have aired, as per WP:TVUPCOMING.-->
{{main|Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. (season 3)}}
{{:Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. (season 3)}}
<!-- To edit the episodes in this section, you need to edit the article listed above. -->
```

What this means is that the actual content is in the article [Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. (season 3)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agents_of_S.H.I.E.L.D._%28season_3%29) (specifically the section Episodes) and that it is transcluded from there.

Comment: Switching to that article as my source worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are after HTML content, use the `rvparse=1` option.